# Изменение фрейма через NSLayoutConstraint

Tags: ios, objective-c

Изменение свойства `constant` не меняет размер фрейма и выдает ошибку. `IBOutlet` в storyboard-е правильный. 
[image: storyboard]

Ошибка появляется в строке с присвоением новой константы, изначальное значение 263.

```
self.heightConstraint.constant = 1115;
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

текст ошибки:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
Try this: 
    (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
    (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x147d7b00 V:[UIView:0x15fc41c0(1115)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14771cb0 V:[UIView:0x147eba20]-(0)-[UIView:0x15fc41c0]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14709e10 V:[UIView:0x147eba20]-(263)-[UIView:0x15fa7b90]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x146ba4b0 V:[UIView:0x15fc41c0]-(0)-[UIView:0x15fa7b90]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x147d7b00 V:[UIView:0x15fc41c0(1115)]>
```

Что я делаю неправильно ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У тебя конфликтуют констрейны. Первая с какой-то еще. Кажется, с четвертой. Посмотри, последний констрейн тебе точно нужен? Если да, то можешь поставить ему приоритет поменьше

Comment: А можно ли как вычислить какой это констрейнт в сторибоарде?

Comment: спасибо, вычислил мешающий констрейнт - изменение приоритета помогло

Comment: На самом деле помог простой перевод ошибки :)